# How can I add data from my custom plugin to the Entry Listing table?

Tags: plugin-development

I've built a custom field that stores its data in its own table. How can I get data from MyCustomField to show up as a column in the Entries Table?

A few details:

- My custom field is made up of multiple fields, in this case a Date/Time field and a text field.
- My custom field is is returned as an array by the `prepValue()` function in my fieldtype file.
- Not every entry will have a record in my custom field's table

How can I check to see if a value exists in my custom field's table for an entry and display it in the Entries Table?

*I'm copying this over from the Craft Slack channel so we don't lose the solution.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will take two hooks in the `MyCustomPlugin.php` file to display data from the custom field.

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == '*')
    {
        unset($attributes['expiryDate']);
        $attributes['whatever-you-want'] = Craft::t('Desired Table Heading');
    }
}
```

The `modifyEntryTableAttributes()` hook will allow us to add/remove columns from the Entries Listing table. Note that the `$attributes[]` variable will automatically try to match up whatever you put in there with an attribute on the entries.

This is probably all you need to drop a standard custom field into the table. However, since my custom field is an array, holding multiple bits of data, we need to use the `getEntryTableAttributes()` hook to dig in to my custom field and grab the item we want to display.

```
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'whatever-you-want')
    {
        // Assign my custom field to a variable
        $fieldData = $entry->mycustomfield;

        // Check if there is any data in the variable
        if (!empty($fieldData)) {

            // If so, return the specific key AS A STRING to the table
            return $fieldData['myCustomDate']->format('n/j/y');
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Notice the `return '';` at the end? That's important, because if an entry DOESN'T have my custom field attached to it, it will try to look up the `$attribute['whatever-you-want']` assuming that's a legitimate DB column, and will fail.

Comment: There is another great explanation of this here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/adding-additional-attributes-to-modifyentrytableattributes/9817?noredirect=1#comment12849_9817