# Customize elementSelect Field's Modal Table Layout

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I am using the "Select Entry" field (`_includes/forms/elementSelect.html`) field in a custom plugin to select one of my custom element types.

In my ElementType, I defined `defineTableAttributes()` and `getTableAttributeHtml()` to customize the table cells on a index view of the Element.

Now when I am using this Element in a modal view, it displays the same cells as on the index view, but I would like to hide certain fields (like buttons).

Is there a way to customize the returned fields, without building the whole modal myself, like mentioned [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-elementtype-modal-ui-for-a-custom-field-type-plugin)?

I saw, that a attribute `context` gets passed, which is either `modal` or `index`, but I don't know how I could access it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want with a combination of the [getTableAttributeHtml()](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) hook and the [modifyEntryTableAttributes()](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntryTableAttributes) hook. You may be able to use the parameter `$source` from `modifyEntryTableAttributes()` to filter out index vs modal.

[Check out this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/adding-additional-attributes-to-modifyentrytableattributes) for a more detailed description.

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't knew 'index'/'modal' was a source actually